# Parcel: unable to marshal value android.util.Pair

Tags: java, android, runtimeexception, parcel

I am using a array list of pair, and trying to pass it to show an error dialog.
The error dialog shows up without any issues, but When the page is paused, I get the below error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(23733): Process: com.comcast.xfinityhome.tps, PID: 23733
E/AndroidRuntime(23733): java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value android.util.Pair@cbb909ad
E/AndroidRuntime(23733): at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1337)
E/AndroidRuntime(23733): at android.os.Parcel.writeList(Parcel.java:711)
E/AndroidRuntime(23733): at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1284)
E/AndroidRuntime(23733): at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:638)
E/AndroidRuntime(23733): at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1313)
E/AndroidRuntime(23733): at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1096)
E/AndroidRuntime(23733): at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:663)
E/AndroidRuntime(23733): at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.writeToParcel(Fragment.java:136)


        ArrayList<Pair> errorData = new ArrayList<>(2);

        errorData.add(Pair.create("Value", "123"));
        errorData.add(Pair.create("name", "number"));

showErrorDialog(...., errorData);
```

Comment: That's expected. You use non-serializable data in a place that expects (but does not check) serializable data. Try a Map instead.

Comment: But its been set as serializable to the fragment its passed in Bundle. NewDialogFragment fragment = new NewDialogFragment(); Bundle args = new Bundle(); args.putSerializable(ERROR_DATA, errorData); fragment.setArguments(args);

Comment: the `ArrayList` itself is and that is why it's not complaining. But nothing checks that all the elements in the list are (until it actually tries to serialize them). And http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Pair.html is not. What should work is to replace `List<Pair<String, String>>` with `Map<String, String>`

Comment: Thanks, let me try that. Since it was just 2 strings, I fixed by passing 2 string arguments.

Answer (score -1):

Extend your class using Parcelable. Read this [tuto](http://www.tutos-android.com/parcelable-android)

Also, you can go to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25791787/unable-to-marshal-value-on-serializable-data) question asked earlier.